# Galleria Images smaller than stage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, galleria

I've got an galleria gallery and my stage has a size of 300x200px but the images contained are resized to 280x130px so there's a border around the images and they are centered inside the stage area.

Is there any way to get rid of this behavior and resize images to 100% of the stage width/height if possible?

Stage width/height is set on init:

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
   height: 200, 
   width: 300, 
   extend: function() {...} //some functionality for an additional navigation
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Classic theme, you might want to have a look at the CSS, more specifically here:

https://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/master/src/themes/classic/galleria.classic.css#L17-23

You might also need to adjust the imageMargin setting:

http://galleria.io/docs/1.2/options/imageMargin/